# USB Gadget Size Limitation - Mass Storage Emulation

Tags: linux, usb, storage, size, emulation

I'm facing a challenge with my Raspberry Pi 4 and software setup. The Pi connects to my server to download a weekly-updated database. The problem arises from the Mass Storage Gadget's CD emulator, which limits storage to 2.3 GB, while my database is almost 6 GB (using ISO file).

I believe i've come across this issue: "That means some restrictions, especially a hardcoded limit on the size of a backing (.iso) file. In case the file size exceeds 1152000 2KiB blocks (approx. 2.36GB / 2.2GiB), the driver will complain "file too big" and limit the usable range (sector count). If the filesystem driver on the USB host requests any sector beyond that, it will encounter I/O errors ("attempt to access beyond end of device")." from https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Mass_storage

Some potential fixes i found:

- https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/3/7/388
- https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/openbmc/patch/20210626211820.107310-5-i.kononenko@yadro.com/

Has anyone faced this issue and has any idea how to proceed?

Comment: So, it would seem from the lkml thread you linked to, that the CD-ROM emulation is the wrong kind of USB gadget!

Comment: Reading https://docs.kernel.org/usb/mass-storage.html , have you tried loading the gadget kernel module with the read-only, but without the CD-ROM flag?

Comment: So thinking this a bit further: for which *purpose* exactly are you emulating a mass storage device? What's the thing reading from your USB gadget?